# Add a Mef's Assembly Path to the AppDomain's .Load Path

Tags: .net, mef, .net-assembly

I have an application that loads certain (extensible) functionality from via Mef. Because these modules (might) utilize 3rd party controls (Telerik) I want to minimize user-perceived loading times (upon opening the forms using the aforementioned controls), I want to pre-load the assemblies these Mef modules reference.

What I am doing is using the Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies(..) method to get the names of referenced assemblies per Mef module and try to Assembly.Load(..) them.

As the modules are located 'somewhere' on the filesystem (typically different from the ExecutingAssembly's path) the loading fails for references of these Mef modules that are not in the Gac.

Is there any way to modify my AppDomain.CurrentDomain's assembly load path? I know of the AppDomain.AssemblyLoad event, but utilizing this is somewhat cumbersome as each module might reside in different directories.

Answer (score 0):

You used to be able to simply call `AppDomain.AppendPrivatePath`, but this method is now marked as obselete because it can introduce load-order issues ([read here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2009/05/14/why-is-appdomain-appendprivatepath-obsolete.aspx)). The recommended approach is to either update your config to include the additional paths, or use `AppDomainSetup.PrivateBinPath` (but that latter would be for when you are creating new application domains).

To apply the config change:

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>
      </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
</configuration>
```

(Lifted straight from the [associated MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/823z9h8w.aspx)). Notice that you can specify multiple probing paths by separating them with a semicolon. You can risk using `AppDomain.AppendPrivatePath(...)`, it still exists as of .NET BCL v4.0, but its marked as obselete for a reason.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. I tried the AppDomain.AppendPrivatePath but that didn't work and interestingly after calling that method, the AppDomain's .PrivatePath property was/is still empty and loading still fails. I also came across the <probing> part in the app.config, but problem is, the path(s) are 'dynamic'. What I am curios about is how MEF handles this - because if I let .Net do its normal, lazy loading of required assembly-references it works perfectly fine.